# Interpretation of higher order multivariate differential.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential

I'm having trouble with this definition of the higher order differential that I'm presented:

If $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is k-times continuously differentiable in a neighbourhood of $x_0 \in U$, then the differential of order k

$d^{(k)}f(x_0):\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \times ... \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$

is explained as symmetric k-linear mapping through:

$d^{(k)}f(x_0)(v_1,...,v_k) = \partial_{v_1},...,\partial_{v_k}f(x_0), (v_1,...,v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n)$

The definition continues by providing examples for different orders:

$d^{(1)}f(x_0)v = \partial_vf(x_0) = lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+tv)-f(x_0)}{t} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x_0) v^i$ for $v = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
v^1\\
\vdots\\
v^n\\
\end{array}
\right) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

finally arriving at:

$d^{(k)}f(x_0)(v_1,...,v_k) = \sum_{i_1,...,i_k = 1}^n \frac{\partial^kf(x_0)}{\partial x_{i1}...\partial x_{ik}} v_1^{(i_1)}...v_k^{(i_k)}$ for $v_i = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
v_i^1\\
\vdots\\
v_i^n\\
\end{array}
\right), 1 \leq i \leq k$.

Im confused by the very first definition, as I can't imagine what $d^{(k)}f(x_0)(v_1,...,v_k)$ is even aiming for. I know the following lines look like the directional derivatives for different $v$, but why would we bring them up in the definition of the higher order differential? Any explanation of the definition is highly appreciated. Also, I think an example (or a link to an example) would really help me.

Comment: Maybe try yourself to apply this definition at least twice to a smooth function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. What objection is the first derivative and what the second?!

Comment: I of course meant *object :).

Comment: @hal4math I tried it on paper, but I still don't understand the reason for which we define with vector $v_i$ which will only give a factor in the form of the entries of the vector. Same for a definition I'm reading in the same script on Taylor-Series, which is defined as: $f(x_0+v) = \sum_{j=o}^k \frac{1}{j!} d^{(j)}f(x_0) (v,...,v)$ (j-times) $+R_{k+1}(x_0,v)$. This definition also differs from the one I know from when I learned about this on my own which just defines: $T_{a,n}(x) = \sum_{|k|\leq n} \frac{D^k f (a) \cdot (x-a)^k}{k!}$ which I understand and have used on real tasks.

Comment: I just think I'm missing some general point.

Comment: These definition actually match up. What do you mean by "only give a factor in the form of the entries"? Also $|k|$. I think you mean $k$? Or is it a multi-index?

Comment: Ah you mean a multi index there. Are you aware of that?

Comment: I think I do understand the indices, I just don't understand why (especially the original question of this thread) is defined with a vector $v$ and why we can't just leave it out.

Comment: I mean do you understand that in your definition of the taylor formula, $k$ actually is a tuple of numbers? Like $(1,0,3)$ in for $3d$, and that $(x-a)^k = (x_1-a_1)(x_3-a_3)^3$? We need those because we have a multilinear map! And that eats a bunch of vectors and then spits out a vector!

Comment: Let me say it like this, Now you commute this example from above. Now take another total derivative. Then you already have a $2\times 2$ matrix! Now every entry needs to be differentiated to respect with first and second coordinate, right? So you get some like two matrixes, but that we just call multilinear. Now, for the second derivate you get the Matrix and now (since we "linearized") we want to be able to get to $\mathbb{R}^2$, now for the second total derivate we just need one vector. But for the third total derivate (since we have something like two matrixes) we need also two vectors.

Comment: @hal4math do you speak German by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I do speak German.

Comment: Könntest du mir das ganze dann vielleicht nochmal auf deutsch erklären? Weil mein  fehlendes Verständnis wie ich glaube an der "doppelten" Sprachbarriere liegt.

Comment: @hal4math Da ich nämlich auch deutsch-Muttersprachler bin und merke, wie schnell sich Dinge schon in meinen Übersetzungen verlieren :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99129/discussion-between-psyph-and-hal4math).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If someone is interested I can also translate this german answer below into english (later)**

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$ Nimm dir mal einen Vektoren (oder Richtung) $v\in\R^2$, und eine Abbildung $f : \R^2 \to \R$, die du gerne verstehen möchtest. Dann ist $\nabla f : \R^2 \times \R^2 \to \R$, warum? Weil einmal können die partiellen Ableitungen $\frac{\partial}{\partial 1} f : \R^2 \to \R$ und $\frac{\partial}{\partial 2} f : \R^2 \to \R$ an einem Punkt im $\R^2$ ausgewertet werden, z.B. am Punkt $x_0 \in \R^2$ und dann kann noch die lineare Abbildung $\nabla f(x) : \R^2 \to \R$. So das man Ende durch 
$$
\nabla f(x) \cdot h = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial 1} f(x) & \frac{\partial}{\partial 2} f) 
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\ v_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
in $\R$ landet. Nun kann ich solche Abbildung aber verschieden interpretieren und während $\nabla f(x)$ stets eine lineare Abbildung ist, muss $\nabla f (\cdot) v :\R^2 \to \R$ keine lineare Abbildung sein, sondern ist wieder eine neue Funktion! Lass und also setzen $g(x) := \nabla f(x)v$. Dann können wir wieder das Differential von $g$ berechnen und erhalten und in der gleichen Richtung $v$ auswerten: 
$$
\nabla g(x)
 =   
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial 1} g(x) &
\frac{\partial}{\partial 2} g(x)
\end{pmatrix}
 =   
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial 1} (\nabla f(x)v) & \frac{\partial}{\partial 2} (\nabla f(x)v).
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Wie du siehst ist $\nabla g(x)$ also auch eine lineare Abbildung von $\R^2 \to \R$, also können wir auch diese lineare Abbildung an $v \in \R^2$ auswerten:
$\nabla g(x) v$ um wieder in $\R$ zu landen. Nun ist aber genauso wie oben $\nabla g(\cdot) v : \R^2 \to \R$ wieder eine ganz normale Funktion, die wir ableiten können. Setze also $h(x) := \nabla g(x) v$ und berechne $\nabla h$. Wie du nun siehst hast du dann 
$$
\nabla h(x)v = \nabla (\nabla g(x)v) v = \nabla \Big(\nabla \big(\nabla f(x)v\big)v\Big)v 
$$
und wie du siehst braucht es 3 $v$s, um diese Abbildung nach $\R$ zu schicken. Nun ist natürlich diese Schreibweise da oben, alles andere als leserfreundlich und daher haben wir uns soetwas ausgedacht wie eine multilineare Abbildung, so dass ich auch schreiben kann:
$$
d^{(3)} f (x) (v,v,v) = \nabla \Big(\nabla \big(\nabla f(x)v\big)v\Big)v.
$$

Ich hoffe, das macht es etwas klarer?